# How can I go about saving the state of my panels to my DB without using PHP

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

The link below explains exactly what I am trying to do, and I have used it as a guide for my implementation so far. I have two columns filled with panels that can be moved around or collapsed. In the end, I want to save the state information about each panel on drop(as soon as the user changes it) so that when each individual user leaves or logs off, everything is where they left it upon return. I am using jquery, and c#.net for my back-end, which from what I understand makes it very difficult to incorporate PHP. I am wondering if anyone knows how I can accomplish what is demonstrated in the link, but using a method that does not include PHP?

http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/saving-state-for-collapsible-drag-drop-panels/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You seem a bit lost (nothing wrong about it), but since you're using C#, you should find a way in C# to access your database. PHP is just a server-side language you could use, but it means installing PHP on your server... and I don't think this is what you want/need.

I'm pretty sure, there are very nice tutorials on the web on how you can interact with your current DB (what are you using? MySQL?)

Basic tutorial for SQL with C# https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EpYqtSlOr8

Comment: You are right about me being a bit lost. I am new at this. I am using MSSQL. I currently have an array filled with each important piece of information about the panel (id, collapsed, userID, etc) in the jquery, which I then serialize into a variable, and deserialize in the c#.(I am thinking this is where I insert the info into my widget table) I guess what I am most unsure about is how to make all of this happen "on- drop" and use the current values in the table for each widget to display them upon returning to the page. I will watch the link, thank you for the response.